# Merge two JSON Objects in MS SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have two json objects :

```
"Celebrity": [
    {
      "Name": "SRK",
      "Surname": "Kajol"
},{
     "Name": "Ajay",
     "Surname": "Devgan"
}]

"Cricketer": [
    {
      "Name": "Virat",
      "Surname": "Kohli"
},{
     "Name": "Sachin",
     "Surname": "Tendulkar"
}]
```

I want to merge the above two arrays into a single JSON array:

```
{"Celebrity": [
    {
      "Name": "SRK",
      "Surname": "Kajol"
},{
     "Name": "Ajay",
     "Surname": "Devgan"
}],

"Cricketer": [
    {
      "Name": "Virat",
      "Surname": "Kohli"
},{
     "Name": "Sachin",
     "Surname": "Tendulkar"
}]}
```

How to I do this merge in MS sql ?

Comment: I don't see a new array, just a new root object containing those two arrays. And the original data is not valid as it has no root object

Comment: I am able to get the two json objects separately but while joining them I am getting error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Original answer:**

A possible approach is using `JSON_MODIFY()` and `JSON_QUERY()`, but you need at least SQL Server 2016 to use the built-in JSON support. The idea is to extract the `"Cricketer"` JSON array from the second JSON (using `JSON_QUERY()` with the appropriate path) and append it to the first JSON (using `JSON_MODIFY()`):

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json1 nvarchar(max) = N'{"Celebrity": [
    {"Name": "SRK", "Surname": "Kajol"},
    {"Name": "Ajay", "Surname": "Devgan"}
]}'
DECLARE @json2 nvarchar(max) = N'{"Cricketer": [
    {"Name": "Virat", "Surname": "Kohli"},
    {"Name": "Sachin", "Surname": "Tendulkar"}
]}'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT @json1 = JSON_MODIFY(@json1, '$."Cricketer"', JSON_QUERY(@json2, '$."Cricketer"'))
SELECT @json1
```

Result:

```
{"Celebrity": [
    {"Name": "SRK", "Surname": "Kajol"},
    {"Name": "Ajay", "Surname": "Devgan"}
],"Cricketer":[
    {"Name": "Virat", "Surname": "Kohli"},
    {"Name": "Sachin", "Surname": "Tendulkar"}
]}
```

**Update:**

If you want to build a JSON output from different tables, the approach below is also an option:

```
SELECT 
   Celebrity = (SELECT Name, Surname FROM TableA FOR JSON AUTO),
   Cricketers = (SELECT Name, Surname FROM TableB FOR JSON AUTO)
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

**SQL Server 2022:**

Starting from SQL Server 2022, a combination of `JSON_OBJECT()` and `JSON_QUERY()` is also an option:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
   'Celebrity': JSON_QUERY(@json1, '$.Celebrity'),
   'Cricketer': JSON_QUERY(@json2, '$.Cricketer')
)
```

Comment: Updating the JSON fields : {"Celebrity": [ {"Id": 1, "Name": "SRK", "Surname": "Kajol"},{"Id": 2, "Name": "Ajay", "Surname": "Devgan"}]}

Comment: Updating the JSON fields : {"Celebrity": [ {"Id": 1, "Name": "SRK", "Surname": "Kajol"},{"Id": 2, "Name": "Ajay", "Surname": "Devgan"}]}    and {"Cricketers": [ {"Id": 1, "Name2": "SRK", "Surname2": "Kajol"},{"Id": 2, "Name2": "Ajay", "Surname2": "Devgan"}]}
Below json queries to fetch as JSON:
Select Name, Surname, Name2, Id, from dbo.CELEBRITY LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CRICKETERS ck ON CELEBRITY.Id = ck.Id FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Action')
Similarly doing on another table and getting JSON Objects... want those two be UNION ALL

Comment: @ParamitaDas It's not clear what you want, but the updated answer may help.

Comment: Pretty disappointingly select JSON_MODIFY(N'{}', '$.a', json_query (N'{"a": []}' , '$.a')); gives {"a":[]}, but select JSON_MODIFY(N'{}', '$.a', json_query (N'{"a": 3}' , '$.a')); gives {}

Comment: @user1593165, this is the expected result. `JSON_QUERY()` extracts JSON object, not JSON scalar value. But `select JSON_MODIFY(N'{}', '$.a', json_value (N'{"a": 3}' , '$.a'));`  returns `{"a":"3"}`.